# How to send mail confirmation with API PLATFORM

Tags: php, symfony, email, api-platform.com

I'm trying to send mail on subscription with API platform, I have read the documentation but I can't call the function and I don't get the good parameters to call it.

I don't understand how to put the correct event as a parameter, I tried to create the event but it asks for a lot of parameters that I don't understand.

Here you can see my code Thank's...

```
<?php


namespace App\Controller;


use ApiPlatform\Core\EventListener\EventPriorities;
use App\Entity\User;
use App\Form\UsersType;
use App\Kernel;
use Exception;
use FOS\RestBundle\Controller\AbstractFOSRestController;
use Lexik\Bundle\JWTAuthenticationBundle\Services\JWTTokenManagerInterface;
use Lexik\Bundle\JWTAuthenticationBundle\Tests\Functional\Utils\CallableEventSubscriber;
use Symfony\Component\EventDispatcher\EventSubscriberInterface;
use Symfony\Component\Form\Form;
use Symfony\Component\Form\FormInterface;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;
use Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Event\RequestEvent;
use Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Event\ViewEvent;
use Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\HttpKernelInterface;
use Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\KernelEvents;
use Symfony\Component\Routing\Annotation\Route;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\JsonResponse;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Encoder\UserPasswordEncoderInterface;
use FOS\RestBundle\View\View as FosRestView;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response;



class UsersController extends AbstractFOSRestController
{
    private $mailer;

    public function __construct(\Swift_Mailer $mailer)
    {
        $this->mailer = $mailer;
    }
    public static function getSubscribedEvents()
    {
        return [
            KernelEvents::VIEW => ['sendMail', EventPriorities::POST_WRITE],
        ];
    }

    public function sendMail($event){

        $user = $event->getControllerResult();

        $method = $event->getRequest()->getMethod();

        if (!$user instanceof User || Request::METHOD_POST !== $method) {
            return;
        }

        $message = (new \Swift_Message('A new book has been added'))
            ->setFrom('xxx@xxx.fr')
            ->setTo('xxxx@xxxx.fr')
            ->setBody(sprintf('Bienvenu', $user->getEmail()));

        $this->mailer->send($message);
    }

    /**
     * @Route(name="login", path="/log-in", methods={"POST"})
     * @param Request $request
     * @param JWTTokenManagerInterface $JWTManager
     * @param UserPasswordEncoderInterface $encoder
     * @return JsonResponse
     */
    public function loginAction(Request $request, JWTTokenManagerInterface $JWTManager, UserPasswordEncoderInterface $encoder)
    {
        $repository = $this->getDoctrine()->getRepository(User::class);

        $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
        $data = json_decode($request->getContent(), true);

        /** @var User $user */
        $user = $repository->findOneBy(["username" => $data['username']]);

        $userPassword = $em->getRepository(User::class)->findOneByUserForPassword($data['username']);

        if ($userPassword == $encoder->encodePassword($user, $data['password'])){
            return new JsonResponse(['token' => $JWTManager->create($user)]);
        } else {
            return new JsonResponse([
                'message' => "Invalid Credentials."
                ], Response::HTTP_UNAUTHORIZED);
        }
    }

    /**
     * @Route(name="register", path="/register", methods={"POST"})
     * @param Request $request
     * @param UserPasswordEncoderInterface $encoder
     * @return FosRestView|Response
     * @throws Exception
     */
    public function registerAction(Request $request, UserPasswordEncoderInterface $encoder)
    {

        $data = json_decode($request->getContent(), true);

        $user = new User;

        $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
        $user->setCreatedAt(new \DateTime());
        //Todo :Improve
        $user->setIsBanned(false);
        $user->setRoles([User::ROLE_USER]);


        //throw Exception if password do not match
        if ($data['password'] != $data['retyped_password'])
        {
            throw new Exception("Passwords do not match");
        }

        //Encoded password using sodium algorithm
        $data['password'] = $encoder->encodePassword($user, $data['password']);

        try {
            $form = $this->createForm(UsersType::class, $user);

            /** @var Form $form*/
            $form->submit($data);

            if (!$form->isValid())
            {
                $errors = array();

                //Parse errors to print in Json format
                foreach ($form->getErrors() as $error) {
                    $errors[$form->getName()][] = $error->getMessage();
                }

                foreach ($form as $child /** @var Form $child */) {
                    if (!$child->isValid()) {
                        foreach ($child->getErrors() as $error) {
                            $errors[$child->getName()][] = $error->getMessage();
                        }
                    }
                }

                return new JsonResponse([
                    $errors
                ], Response::HTTP_BAD_REQUEST);
            }

            if ($form->isSubmitted())
            {
                $em->persist($user);
                $em->flush();

                // Heere I Try to send the mail 
                $event = self::getSubscribedEvents();
                $this->sendMail($event);
            }
            return $this->json($user, Response::HTTP_CREATED);


            //return $user;
        } catch (\Exception $exception) {
            return new JsonResponse(['message' => $exception->getMessage()], Response::HTTP_BAD_REQUEST);
        }

    }



}
```

Comment: https://symfony.com/doc/current/mailer.html#creating-sending-messages

Comment: Thanks for answers but this way use twig ? does it work with an API ?

Comment: There's no twig involved in the first example on that link. It only says that you _can_ use twig if you want. And then it's only to use twig as a mail template (for the mail contents), which would be the same regardless if your application is an API or not.

Comment: ok I will try thank's :)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to send mail when a new book is added with POST request, you can do it with a Subscriber with the same event you are used in your controller. But it runs only with API Platform : i say that because i see your controller extends AbstractFosController. So what's API you're using : FOSRestBundle or APï Platform ?

If you use API Platform
First, remove `getSubscribedEvents()` from your controller.
Create a class SendMailSubscriber in listener directory.
Your class will be like this :

```php
namespace <namespace>;

use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response;
use Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Event\GetResponseForControllerResultEvent;
use Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\KernelEvents;

class EmailSubscriber implements EventSubscriberInterface
{
 
    protected $mailService;
    
    public function __construct(MailService $mailService)
    {
        $this->mailService = $mailService;
    }

    public static function getSubscribedEvents(): array
    {
        return [
            KernelEvents::VIEW => ['sendMail', EventPriorities::POST_WRITE],
        ];
    }

    private function sendMail(GetResponseForControllerResultEvent $event)
    {
        $user = $event->getControllerResult();
        $method = $event->getRequest()->getMethod();

        if ($user instanceof UserType
            && Request::METHOD_POST === $method
        ) {
            $this->mailService->sendMail();      
        }
    }

}
```

services.yml :

```
  Path\To\Listener\EmailSubscriber:
    autoconfigure: true
    autowire: true
    tags:
      - { name: kernel.event_subscriber, event: kernel.view }
```

And create a service MailService who injects SwiftMailer (if you are on Symfony 4+, use Mailer component, not SwiftMailer).
When  a new entry via POST request will be executed, the subscriber will send automatically email via MailerService

This is an example, not the full correct code, good luck :)